# How do I let main thread suspend and wait for the System.Timer.Timer running

Tags: c#

Hi I am using System.Timer.Timer

I always get NULL after running my programme and it only works if I add this.sleep(6000). Suppose the reason is the main thread ends but the timer hasn't finished ... 
Here is the class and I call the class from my main form.

```
Class class1
{
  string finalResult = "";
  public string getNumber()
  {
    RunTimer();  
    return finalResult;
  }
  pubic void RunTimer ()
  {
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
    timer.Interval = 1000;         
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(cal);
    timer.Start();
  }
  private void cal(object sender,System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
    finalResult += READFROMCOMPORT;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TimerCallback

http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/pnetlib-doc/System/Threading/Timer.html

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to use a timer in this instance?

If you want this to be a synchronous operation and wait for finalresult to get populated, you could just wait 6 seconds before returning READFROMCOMPORT.

**EDIT:** If you need the program to continue running, you could create a callback event that you bind to after you instantiate the class.  Once the timer expires, you can raise the callback event and pass your new value

**EDIT 2:** an easy way to implement this sort of asynchronous'ness is to use a BackgroundWorker component.  the backgroundworker has a DoWork() method which contains your asynchrnous code, as well as a "RunWorkerCompleted" callback event which you can subscribe to to get your asynchronous result.  See here for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: If I make the whole programme sleep, user lose all the controlls. And the waiting time could be more than 6 seconds like 30.
I don't think it is a good solution to make the main thread sleep for 30 seconds

Comment: Then you have to call the whole thing on another thread, if you can.  The main thread is returning as soon as you run the timer, so no matter what, you wont get your value returned unless you keep them both off the main thread, so that you can either combine them into one thread or make thread 2 wait for thread 3 (which obviously doesnt make much sense)

Comment: Callback only exists in Threading.Timer?
I am using System.Timer.Timer

Comment: Please see my second edit.  Also, the other posters are right, I dont advocate using Thread.Sleep at all, I'm removing it from my answer :-)

Comment: I have to wrap this class into the API
and I found problem while async with the main form

Comment: Like what?  Please be a little more specific, and maybe we'll be able to identify the problem.

Answer (score 3):

A good rule of thumb is to never use `Thread.Sleep` in production code. Its presence usually indicates poor threading design.

Instead, listen to the COM Port's `DataReceived` event.

Comment: But the data will be sent to COM port continuously, that's why I need a timer to listen to the port in every second.

Comment: Or you can just respond to `DataReceived`, which fires when more data arrives. No timer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already calling GetNumber() from a separate thread from the GUI, ditch the timer, do the work in GetNumber(), and the thread will stop returning early.  In any case, don't use Thread.Sleep because there's no way to unblock it if you need to, or if the app quits. Use Monitor.Wait instead, which can be unblocked with Monitor.Pulse.